How to make combined legend for ggplots using either patchwork() or ggarrange() etc
I am struggling to make a legend that I want for my graph. Here is what the graph currently looks like (it's not a final version, I know it's not super pretty)

I am frustrated by the fact that I can't seem to combine the legends into one using patchwork or ggarrange packages. I am used to using scale_fcn_manual() and making the aesthetic calls identical, then calling for "collected" legends in patchwork(). However, because the data within each plot is actually different, it is still making them into 3 separate plot legends, despite the fact that I have all possible treatment options in my code.
Does anyone know how to either create an entirely new legend from scratch or fix my code? I have tried using a common legend using ggarrange() as well, but got a similar result. Below, I will include my ggplot code and also what I would LIKE the figure to look like, manually edited on Paint. Thanks!

plot_size_p = ggplot (filter(snail_size, food %in% c("C","J","K","L")), aes(x = week, y = mean_size, color = food, shape=infected, linetype=infected)) +
  labs(color = "Resource Type",
       linetype = "Parasite Status",
       shape = "Parasite Status")+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=mean_size-SEM_size, ymax=mean_size+SEM_size, color=food)) +
  geom_point (aes(color = food, shape=infected)) +
  geom_line (aes(color = food, linetype=infected))+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("F","I","H","G","L","K","J","O","N","M","C"),labels = c("100% Pleco Wafers","High N","Med N","Low N","High P","Med P","Low P","High (N+P)","Med (N+P)","Low (N+P)", "Baseline"),values = c("green4", brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[5],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[5],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[5], "grey"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks=c(0,1), labels=c("Uninfected","Infected"), values=c(1,2))+
  scale_shape_manual(breaks=c(0,1), labels=c("Uninfected","Infected"), values=c(19,17))

plot_size_n = ggplot (filter(snail_size, food %in% c("C","G","H","I")), aes(x = week, y = mean_size, color = food, shape=infected, linetype=infected)) +
  labs(color = "Resource Type",
       linetype = "Parasite Status",
       shape = "Parasite Status")+
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=mean_size-SEM_size, ymax=mean_size+SEM_size, color=food)) +
  geom_point (aes(color = food, shape=infected)) +
  geom_line (aes(color = food, linetype=infected))+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("F","I","H","G","L","K","J","O","N","M","C"),labels = c("100% Pleco Wafers","High N","Med N","Low N","High P","Med P","Low P","High (N+P)","Med (N+P)","Low (N+P)", "Baseline"),values = c("green4", brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[5],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[5],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[5], "grey"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks=c(0,1), labels=c("Uninfected","Infected"), values=c(1,2))+
  scale_shape_manual(breaks=c(0,1), labels=c("Uninfected","Infected"), values=c(19,17))

plot_size_np = ggplot (filter(snail_size, food %in% c("C","M","N","O")), aes(x = week, y = mean_size, color = food, shape=infected, linetype=infected)) +
  labs(color = "Resource Type",
       linetype = "Parasite Status",
       shape = "Parasite Status")+
  geom_point (aes(color = food, shape=infected)) +
  geom_line (aes(color = food, linetype=infected))+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("F","I","H","G","L","K","J","O","N","M","C"),labels = c("100% Pleco Wafers","High N","Med N","Low N","High P","Med P","Low P","High (N+P)","Med (N+P)","Low (N+P)", "Baseline"),values = c("green4", brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[5],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[6],brewer.pal(9, "Blues")[5],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[7],brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[6], brewer.pal(9, "Purples")[5], "grey"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks=c(0,1), labels=c("Uninfected","Infected"), values=c(1,2))+
  scale_shape_manual(breaks=c(0,1), labels=c("Uninfected","Infected"), values=c(19,17))

size_plots = wrap_plots(plot_size_p,plot_size_n,plot_size_np, nrow = 1, ncol = 3)+ 
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
size_plots


It will be dramatically easier for people to give you relevant answers if you can make your question reproducible. I'd also suggest removing most/all of the formatting, which might be important for your final output, but is irrelevant for the purposes of the question.

I was wondering if I should use the iris dataset or something. I'm not sure what part of the formatting is or isn't useful, to be honest, as often I find that ggplot() proper output depends greatly on how things are called. Definitely can edit out a lot of stuff though, let me do that now.

Perhaps I don't understand the structure of your data well enough, but I would have expected that using facets would be the easiest way to do this. Is there a reason not to do so here?

Try with setting the same limits, i.e. add limits =  c("F","I","H","G","L","K","J","O","N","M","C")  to scale_color_manual. But I agree with Jon that facetting would be the easiest way.

I have found that the facets scales the size of the facets weirdly to fit in the legend, which is why I switched to using patchwork() instead anyway. I assume you mean facet_wrap()? Maybe it's just been awhile and now that isn't an issue.

I will also try that limits suggestion!

e.g. snail_size |> mutate(my_facet = case_match(food, c("C","J","K","L") ~ "P\nSupplement", c("C","G","H","I") ~ N\nSupplement, c("C","M","N","O"), "(N+P)\nSupplement")) |> ggplot(aes( ....... + facet_wrap(~my_facet)?

Does this answer work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77592737/r-ggplot2-patchwork-combine-legends-with-comparable-but-different-sets-of-v

... one more note: Besides setting the same limits it is also necessary to add show.legend=TRUE to the geoms (due to a change in ggplot2 >= 3.5.0) to ensure that a key is displayed in the legend for missing categories and to ensure that the legends are identical and get merged.

I will try these suggestions and report back, thank you!

The combination of setting the limits with the show.legend=TRUE made it work! Thanks!

In many cases this is simplest to do with facets. For instance, here I facet by gear, but color by gear+am. That puts two colors into the middle facet:
mtcars |>
  mutate(Resource = paste(gear, am)) |>
  ggplot(aes(wt, mpg, color = Resource)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("3 0", "4 0", "4 1", "5 1"),
                     labels = c("Moose", "Bunny", "Rabbit", "Flour"),
                     values = c("green4", RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[7], 
                                RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[5], "blue")) +
  facet_wrap(~gear)


As @stefan noted in the comments, if we use separate plots with patchwork, we will not see a legend for categories not represented in the data (using ggplot2 >= 3.5.0), unless we add show.legend = TRUE to the geom in question. Compare the three plots below, the first of which omits that. Its guide doesn't match the other guide so it doesn't get combined:

If we add it, the guides can be combined:

my_col_scale <- scale_color_manual(limits =  c("3 0", "4 0", "4 1", "5 1"),
                                  name = "Resource",
                                   labels = c("Moose", "Bunny", "Rabbit", "Flour"),
                                   values = c("green4", RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[7], 
                                              RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Reds")[5], "blue")) 

mtcars |>
  mutate(Resource = paste(gear, am)) -> mtcars2
  

library(patchwork)

wrap_plots(
  ggplot(mtcars2 |> filter(gear == 3), aes(wt, mpg, color = Resource)) +
    geom_point(size = 4) +   # note missing `show.legend = TRUE`
  my_col_scale2,
  
  ggplot(mtcars2 |> filter(gear == 4), aes(wt, mpg, color = Resource)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, show.legend = TRUE) + 
  my_col_scale2,
  
  ggplot(mtcars2 |> filter(gear == 5), aes(wt, mpg, color = Resource)) +
    geom_point(size = 4, show.legend = TRUE) + 
    my_col_scale2
) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")


Thank you! Very thorough, even without my data being reproducible. Thanks for the explanation and alternative method.
